# Bash alias gives different results than just running the command

Tags: macos, bash

I want to find the path of the currently-running Apache daemon on my Mac, so I put this alias in my `~/.profile`:

```
alias which-apache="ps aux | grep -m 1 -e '^_www' -e 'httpd' | awk '{print $11}'"
```

Here's the line the command `ps aux | grep -m 1 -e '^_www' -e 'httpd'` returns, showing that the path is in column 11:

```
_www              826   0.0  0.0  2478580    712   ??  S    12:53PM   0:00.00 /opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
```

The full command with the awk part gives me the correct path, but when I run the alias, all I get is this: `1`.

Why is there a difference between calling the alias and the command?

Comment: You should consider using [`pgrep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$11` is inside double quotes:

```
alias which-apache="ps aux | grep -m 1 -e '^_www' -e 'httpd' | awk '{print $11}'"
#                                                                          ^^^
```

`$1` is expanded to an empty string, and the following alias being added:

```
alias which-apache="ps aux | grep -m 1 -e '^_www' -e 'httpd' | awk '{print 1}'"
#                                                                          ^
```

Escape the `$` sign:

```
alias which-apache="ps aux | grep -m 1 -e '^_www' -e 'httpd' | awk '{print \$11}'"
#                                                                          ^^
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew about variable expansion in bash scripts but didn't realize that my profile is ... just another bash script.

Comment: You may add the following advice your solution, echo the alias to test its value : echo "ps aux | grep -m 1 -e '^_www' -e 'httpd' | awk '{print $11}'"
**ps aux | grep -m 1 -e '^_www' -e 'httpd' | awk '{print 1}'**

Comment: @LittleNooby: or even better type `alias` without arguments

Comment: @LittleNooby: it'll print all the aliases you have added. Try it out ;)

Comment: I just did, it will print $11 rather than 1 so it won't help to detect the problem.

Comment: @LittleNooby: probably that's because you have added the correct (escaped) alias

Comment: My bad, I probably did this.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a Bash function instead of a command:

```
function which-apache {
    ps aux | grep -m 1 -e '^_www' -e 'httpd' | awk '{print $11}'
}
```

You're using double-quotes to define your alias (`alias which-apache="..."`), and the `$11` is being interpreted by Bash, not by `awk`.

If you want to do it with an alias, do it like this:

```
alias which-apache="ps aux | grep -m 1 -e '^_www' -e 'httpd' | awk '{print \$11}'"
```

Or even:

```
alias which-apache='ps aux | grep -m 1 -e "^_www" -e "httpd" | awk \'{print $11}\''
```

Comment: Nice idea using functions. It greatly improves readability and maintenance.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, multiple levels of different types of quoting leads to big maintainability problems. Isn't bash quoting fun?! ;)

Comment: I'll go with the function for maintainability, thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!